# Cardinality of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ without AC

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does $k+\aleph_0=\mathfrak{c}$ imply $k=\mathfrak{c}$ without the Axiom of Choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30282/does-k-aleph-0-mathfrakc-imply-k-mathfrakc-without-the-axiom-of-choic)
>   [Showing that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ are equinumerous using Cantor-Bernstein](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105990/showing-that-mathbbr-and-mathbbr-backslash-mathbbq-are-equinumerous)

What can be said about $|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q|$ under weaker versions of AC or alternative axioms (Martin's axiom, for example)? thank you.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/72140/ and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105990/showing-that-mathbbr-and-mathbbr-backslash-mathbbq-are-equinumerous.

Comment: The second link given by @Jonas contains a complete answer: one can use the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem to show that $|\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q|=|\Bbb R|$ in ZF.